# Git: http.sslVerify false global but only for specific remote

Tags: git, ssl, verification

I'm looking for a way, to disable the Git SSL verification globally but for a single remote only.

The only ways I know about, are these two possibilies:

- Do it globally, for all remotes: `git config --global http.sslVerify false`
- Do it locally in every single remotes repo: `git config --local http.sslVerify false`

But is there a chance to set the config like you can do it with proxy settings? For example:

I have a system wide set proxy config in my `~/.gitconfig`. But instead of overriding it by a local proxy setting, I used:

`git config --global remote.<remote name>.proxy ""` (in this case for a direct connection)

Unfortunately something like the following **does not work**:

`git config --global remote.<remote name>.http.sslVerify false`

Any ideas? Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else stumbles upon this, the way to set `http.sslVerify` for a specific remote from command line would be:

```
git config --global http.<remote name>.sslVerify false
```

e.g.

```
git config --global http.https://gitlab.domain.com/.sslVerify false
```

Answer (score 6):

In the gitconfig you can specify for each remote address both proxy and sslVeryfy like this:

no proxy and sslVerify false

```
[http "https://blah.com/"]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy =
```

and also for all the others proxy and sslVerify false

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = http://yourproxyaddress.com:8080
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this. Thanks!

```
git config --add http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: I am using lets encrypt ssl service and this is causing me to get this error: 
"SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired".

I cant remember the issue, but no time to investigate further.