# fatal: unable to access, schannel: failed to open CA file, No such process, GitHub Desktop

Tags: github, github-desktop

Full error text:

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Repository_name': schannel: failed to open CA file 'C:/Users/Username/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/app-1.2.1/resources/app/git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt': No such process

Application just stopped to work and throwing this error every time when I try to fetch, pull, push or clone any repository. The same commands in bash work correctly

Comment: I hit this error today when I downloaded the new version (2.17.1) that was released on 5-29. I had to downgrade to an older version I had cached in my downloads folder to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hey Andy, how did you downgrade?

Comment: I just reran the installer, but I only had the installer left in my downloads folder by chance.

Comment: Same error here with me, i just applied the new updates in my gitDesktop and now i m unable to fetch any repo and this same error appearing here.

Answer (score 15):

Go to `%ProgramData%/Git` open config file with a text editor and substitute

`sslCAInfo = ... some stuff`  with

`sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

This has been already discussed in this issue on Github https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4817 and it will be fixed asap.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks @simoconfa

Comment: This is the right recommendation. Only in my case, the path is `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\ssl\certs\ca-bundle.crt`

Answer (score 7):

The error I got was:
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/{reponame}.git/': schannel: failed to open CA file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt': No such process`

I fixed it by opening my config file located in "C:\ProgramData\Git\config" and updating the setting as follows `sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

I hope this helps someone

Answer (score 2):

CF [How do I set GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY for specific repos only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008309/how-do-i-set-git-ssl-no-verify-for-specific-repos-only)

I fixed this by running
git config http.sslVerify false
but not sure how secure my GIT comms is now :(

Comment: This is a bad suggestion; see editing the system git config file answers here.

Answer (score 2):

you can use it

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

use it in your repository
or use this command if you dont have a git repo

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Type %ProgramData%/ in Windows search bar(Type here to search field at
   bottom left corner)
2. Go to /Git
3. Open congif file in text editor. (Preferably Notepad++ or similar, as this allows to edit the file Administrator mode. Otherwise, write permission is denied.)
4. Remove this entry from the file

   ```
   [http]
   sslCAInfo = C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
   ```
5. Save and close file.
   Try to push again, it works!

Reference:

[fatal: unable to access curl-ca-bundle.crt #4836](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4836)

[After restarting my client following a desktop client update prompt, I can no longer Fetch Origin #4817](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/4817)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by just removing "C:\ProgramData\Git\config"