# unable to access, schannel: failed to open CA file, No such process, GitHub Desktop

Tags: git, github

I have cloned my project but I have some certificate and other problem but i can't understand it. Please help to resolve this problem.

**Version**
1.2.3

**Operating system:**
windows 8.1

below is error image please see and if you know give me some ideas.

[image]

Comment: seems like a clone of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612862/fatal-unable-to-access-schannel-failed-to-open-ca-file-no-such-process-gith?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 0):

I find below solution

See if you have a file in C:\ProgramData\Git\config and check if that file contains a section similar to this

[http]
    sslCAinfo = /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt

If it does, try removing the sslCAInfo line or change your curl-ca-bundle.crt file path , save the file, and try cloning again from GitHub Desktop

If your internet and firewall security is on so please pause some time and try again.

Thanks to help me