# unable to access 'https://github.com/GladysProject/gladys/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: no route to host

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, raspbian, host, samba

When i run :

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/GladysProject/gladys gladys
```

an error appear :

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/GladysProject/gladys/': Failed to connect to github.com port 443: no route to host
```

I am on last version of raspbian on a raspberry pi 3B, i just got SAMBA and Transmission on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, check your connection settings and all that nonsense, sure you already have though.

If the error persists, turn off SSL verification

```
git config http.sslVerify false
```

but if no repo, run this to change global setting

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

duplicate of [How do I set GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY for specific repos only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008309/how-do-i-set-git-ssl-no-verify-for-specific-repos-only)