# Jenkins: Failed to connect git repository

Tags: jenkins

When I try to give GitHub repository URL in Source Code Management (GIT) in Jenkins, I'm getting this error:

> Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git ls-remote -h https://github.com/chowdarydevops/test.git HEAD

Comment: What does the result of: `GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 GIT_TRACE=1 git ls-remote -h https://github.com/chowdarydevops/test.git HEAD` show?  Also, what operating system and version of git are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the SSL certificate is unable to be verified so SSL/TLS may need to add the relevant CRT for your system.

- These insecure and **NOT** recommended methods may help bypass the verification process for troubleshooting purposes:

```
GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git ls-remote -h https://github.com/chowdarydevops/test.git HEAD
```

or

```
git -c http.sslVerify=false ls-remote -h https://github.com/chowdarydevops/test.git HEAD
```

*see [how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621768/how-can-i-make-git-accept-a-self-signed-certificate) and [how-do-i-set-git-ssl-no-verify-for-specific-repos-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008309/how-do-i-set-git-ssl-no-verify-for-specific-repos-only) for more info*